# How can I find an expression to represent the changes in an image?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

I'm unsure how to approach this. the first layer has six cans, the second has 3 and the third has one. The fourth has no cans but if I had to draw a separate pyramid of cans repeating the pattern it would have four cans on the bottom, 3 cans on the third layer, 2 cans on the second and 1 can on the first. How can I represent this as an expression?

Answer (score 0):

I think this task is ambiguous.

The pattern can mean, that you are building pyramids next to each other, or it can also refer to just one pyramid (and the others are there to demonstrate the pattern).

If you think of a pyramid of  $L$ layers at a time, it is going to have $$1+2+\dots+(L-1) + L = \frac{L(L+1)}{2}$$ cans in it.

However if the question is asking for *all* the pyramids, then the first layer is going to have $$1+2+\dots+N = \sum_{i=1}^N i= \frac{N(N+1)}{2}$$ cans, if there are $N$ pyramids. The second layer is going to have $$1+2+\dots+(N-1) = \sum_{i=1}^{N-1}i= \frac{(N-1)(N+1-1)}{2}$$ cans and in general, the $k^\text{th}$ layer is going to have $$\frac{(N-(k-1))(N + 1 -(k-1))}{2} = \frac{(N-k+1)(N-k+2)}{2}$$ cans.